# Twitter bootstrap not working properly in safari 5.1.7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

Am using below Twitter Bootstrap cnd it is working well with Firefox ,chrome and IE browsers but problem with Safari 5.1.7 browser as well as Iphone 6.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also added

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But not working well in Safari Browser .

hope for the best.

Comment: Could you describe exactly what the problem is? maybe some screenshots will be revelant?

Comment: Images are zooming out , textboxes allignment  and complete alignment is showing clumsy in safari brower .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

You can read that Safari is not fully supported under windows.

And you can see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/browser-bugs/) the official list of bugs.